# "Чисельний аналіз" чи "численний аналіз"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

На слуху два слова, але як правильно "чисельний аналіз" чи "численний аналіз"?

Для мене ці слова схожі за значеннями, але хочеться більш детально розібратися.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75484/discussion-on-question-by-anastasiya-belo4ka------).

Comment: @AnastasiaBelo4ka, а що таке «чисельний/численний/числовний аналіз»? Галузь якої саме науки мається на увазі, для чого той аналіз призначений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мені здається що на один з ваших варіантів вплинуло російське "численный анализ" який перекладається українською як "чисельний аналіз". Можливо хтось переклав "численный" як "численний", але це зовсім змінює смисл виразу. Українською "**численний**" означає ([СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/chyslennyj)):

> ЧИСЛЕ́ННИЙ, а, е.
>   1. Який складається з великої кількості кого-, чого-небудь. *Іноді, замість справжнього диспуту, перед численною аудиторією відбувалося спритно підготоване і розігране інсценування й комедія диспуту (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови, I, 1957, 152).*
>   2. Наявний у великій кількості.  *Небо заступали хмари. Вони насувалися з заходу, закриваючи собою численні зорі (Анатолій Шиян, Баланда, 1957, 190);* 
>   //  Взятий у значній кількості, за багатьма показниками. - численні дані
>   //  Який ставили, провадили не раз.  - численні досліди
>   //  Який відбувається, надходить, трапляється через короткий проміжок часу; частий. - численні спалахи, численні виступи.

На відміну від "численного" [чисельний](http://sum.in.ua/s/chyseljnyj) це:

> ЧИСЕ́ЛЬНИЙ, а, е.
>   1. Стос. до числа (у 1 знач.), виражений числом; числовий. Чисельний аналіз.
>   2. Виражений у якій-небудь кількості; кількісний. Чисельна перевага була на боці гімназистів (Спиридон Добровольський, Олов'яні солдатики, 1961, 118).

Тобто "численний аналіз" так сказати взагалі не можна, можна "численні аналізи" - тобто аналізи, наявні у великій кількості.

А "чисельний аналіз" - це аналіз даних за допомогою математичних [чисельних методів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8):

> **Чи́сельні ме́тоди** — методи наближеного або точного розв'язування задач чистої або прикладної математики, які ґрунтуються на побудові послідовності дій над скінченною множиною **чисел**.

Answer (score 1):

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/chiselniy-i-chislenniy)
[image]

[Літературне слововживання](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53415/32780.html)

***Чисельний*** – 1. Який стосується числа; числовий: чисельний аналіз. 2. Кількісний: чисельна перевага, чисельне зростання населення.

***Численний*** – 1. Який складається з великої кількості когось, чогось: численний загін, численна група, численна організація, численне товариство. 2.Наявний у великій кількості: численні війська, гості, делегації, досліди, жертви, зразки, кадри, мешканці, озера, підприємства, ухвали.